# Postgres insert or update trigger WHEN condition (old)

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I need write insert or update trigger, but with WHEN condition with compare OLD and NEW rows.

According documentation OLD is null for insert operation. How i can use OLD in WHEN condition for INSERT AND UPDATE triggers?

Example trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "mytable"
    FOR EACH ROW 
    WHEN (NEW.score > 0 AND OLD.score <> NEW.score)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE mytrigger();
```

but for insert OLD is null.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: `OLD.score IS NULL` might be useful. Or you could have two separate triggers (that can still share the same procedure).

Comment: but according documentation postgres not garant execute operation order. For example OLD.score may be executed before OLD is null

Comment: INSERT trigger's WHEN condition cannot reference OLD values
LINE 34: ...EW.score IS NOT NULL AND NEW.score <> '' AND (OLD.score. I need seperate on two trigger.

Comment: try to define `when condition` inside the `mytrigger()`

Answer (score 37):

**Option A:**

You can change the code so that conditions will be in the trigger function rather than the trigger itself. With this approach `OLD` will be used only in the `UPDATE`.

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "mytable"
    FOR EACH ROW 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE mytrigger();
```

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytrigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin
if NEW.score > 0 then
     --code for Insert
     if  (TG_OP = 'INSERT') then
           YOUR CODE
     end if;

     --code for update
     if  (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') then
           if OLD.score <> NEW.score then  -- (if score can be null see @voytech comment to this post)
              YOUR CODE
           end if;
     end if;
end if;
return new;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

**Option B:**

As Thilo suggested write two triggers that share the same trigger function.

Triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger1
    BEFORE INSERT ON "mytable"
    FOR EACH ROW 
    WHEN NEW.score > 0
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE mytrigger();


CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger2
    BEFORE UPDATE ON "mytable"
    FOR EACH ROW 
    WHEN (NEW.score > 0 AND OLD.score <> NEW.score)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE mytrigger();
```

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytrigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin
      YOUR CODE
return new;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Comment: Remember that NULL is not equal to NULL - so when comparing OLD.score with NEW.score it would be more wise to use IS DISTINCT FROM statement:
OLD.score IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.score

Comment: @voytech I just copied his condition. We don't know what type `score` is. It can also be `not null` field. We can work only with the information that was provided :) In any case, I edited the code with reference to your comment.

Comment: But i want use went outside trigger for optimize

Comment: @Artemiy StagnantIce Alexeew See Option B

Answer (score -2):

`Trigger.oldMap.keySet();`  will give the Id's present in the `Trigger.oldMap`.
It is a set type collection of all the Id's.
have a look at the following example,  change the DML events in the trigger events every time and see the debug logs.
you will understand which trigger context variable is available for which DML event.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER Email_Check_On_Contact
                 before update{
     oldMap<ID,Contact>=new Map<ID,Contact>();
     o = trigger.oldMap;
     for(Contact newcont: trigger.new)
     {
        if(newcont.Email != o.get(newcont.Id).Email)
        {
            newcont.Email.addError('Email cannot be changed');
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be SQL or PL/pgSQL

Comment: This looks like syntax for Salesforce, which seems unhelpful in a question for Postgres.