# How to throw a SQL error on insertion if n number of duplicate values are detected already in the target table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I have an intersection table consisting of two columns, Training Program and Course. My boss has asked me to structure it so that people will be blocked from adding more than 50 courses to a training program.

I thought I should do this with a trigger.

I was trying to follow along with this...[Postgres insert or update trigger WHEN condition (old)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029446/postgres-insert-or-update-trigger-when-condition-old)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_count_tracks_per_map()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN 
    DECLARE
        val INTEGER;
        BEGIN
            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO val FROM ntnx_track_in_map m WHERE m.map_id = new.map_id; 
    IF val > 49
    THEN 
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'INSERT failed, maximum tracks in map reached'
    END IF;
    RETURN new;
END
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

The error I'm getting is this -- I've tried a couple things syntax wise but it hasn't helped yet, adding and removing ; mostly [image: image of failure]

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps add a ```;``` after the ```RAISE EXCEPTION``` and create the trigger ```BEFORE INSERT```

Comment: I hope you are aware that there is a race condition: two such triggers running concurrently each wouldn't see the `INSERT` from the other transaction. That way you can end ou with counts exceeding the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Issues with your code:

- the `RAISE EXCEPTION` statement must be terminated by a semicolon
- there are two `BEGIN`s, while there should be only one, after the declaration of the variables

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_count_tracks_per_map()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE val INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO val FROM ntnx_track_in_map m WHERE m.map_id = new.map_id; 
        IF val > 49 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'INSERT failed, maximum tracks in map reached';
        END IF;
        RETURN new;
    END
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d62580f98f3b18b4064ce164bb78c2e1)**